# Are connections to databases http based or tcp based

Tags: postgresql, springboot

are connections to Database http based or tcp based.

Are jdbc of spring-boot application to postgressql http method connections based or tcp based connections.

Comment: Does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121872/381289) answer your question? `HTTP` is an application level protocol and usually uses `TCP/IP` as underlying transport protocol, so even databases like **CouchDB** that use `HTTP` also use `TCP/IP`.

Answer (score 1):

Although JDBC connections to PostgreSQL utilize a URL (Uniform Resource Locator), they are not using the HTTP protocol. They don't use TCP port 80, either, if that's what you were asking; they use the default port of 5432 unless you have configured your Postgre server to use a different port. You can find the details [here](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html).

Answer (score 0):

You would usually expect connections that aren’t used for  transportation of hypertext to use something different than Hyper-Text Transport Protocol. The usual way to transport other data with some control over whether it has arrived would probably be a protocol built on top of Transport Control Protocol.